# No option to remove Bluetooth device in iOS Settings app?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, settings

I would like to remove my Raspberry Pi from my iPhone 8 (running iOS 11.2.1) as a connected bluetooth device.

Normally, I would go into my Settings -> Bluetooth and select the Info button (a small blue circled "i") to show the "Disconnect" and "Forget Device" dialogs:

[image: iOS bluetooth circled "i"]

Unfortunately, iOS does not give me this option for my device. The bluetooth device list does not contain an "i" for the item, and there is seemingly no other way to disconnect.

[image]

How do I unpair this device if there is no button to trigger to the unpair prompt?

Due to work restrictions I cannot completely reset the device.

Comment: On my iPhone 7 (IOS 11.2.1) there is a little circled " i " If I tap on that it takes me to an options screen for that device and one selection is "forget this device." Odd that it is not displaying on your phone...

Comment: This is happening to me too! Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Workplaces and schools can prevent bluetooth modifications via an installed configuration profile. Check for the presence of such a profile at  **Settings > General > Profiles**.

Using [Apple Configurator 2](https://support.apple.com/apple-configurator) (an application made by Apple to allow companies & schools to administrate their employee's/student's devices) there is an option:

> Allow Modifying Bluetooth Settings (supervised only)

Unchecking this option in the installed configuration profile will prevent iOS from forgetting the device.

**Note:** It is the same for [Profile Manager in macOS Server](https://support.apple.com/profile-manager)

If you are using iOS with an installed configuration profile, I would suggest contacting your IT department and requesting that they allow you to edit Bluetooth settings.

Heres a picture of what it looks like in Apple Configurator 2:

[image]

Comment: ?? What about iOS devices that are not managed by an IT department?

Answer (score 4):

I've experienced this phenomena as well, usually have restoring from a backup, and found that I had to delete the apps associated with the devices in order to make things work properly.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what apps associated with the devices means? Does a Bose app prevent you from unpairing Bose headphones? Or temperature sensors? This could be exceptionally useful with an edit to explain how to determine an app that disrupts normal bluetooth pairing and unpairing.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. The Garmin dash-cam bluetooth connection was copied over when I got a new phone, but the actual connection never worked, and I couldn't manually remove the camera. Reinstalling the Garmin app forced the bluetooth connection to reset

Answer (score 2):

Delete the app associated with the bluetooth device.

This may remove the device from your iOS bluetooth devices list.