# Unpairing a Bluetooth device when there is no “i”

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I got a Tickr X heart rate monitor. It uses BTLE to interoperate with iPhone and Apple Watch. On the first day I got it, I paired it with my iPhone.

Then I decided to keep it paired with my Apple Watch instead, since that replaces the less-accurate optical heart rate monitor built into the watch.

But, it seems that my iPhone hijacks the Tickr before my Apple Watch can pair with it. When the iPhone shows “Connected” for the Tickr, the watch does not show the Tickr as a health device. When I turn off the iPhone Bluetooth, the Tickr appears on the Apple Watch.

So, to the best of my understanding, I need my iPhone to forget the Tickr and stop auto-connecting to it. But I can’t figure out how to unpair the Tickr from the iPhone — it is the only Bluetooth device that does not have the encircled “i”. How do I make the phone forget this device? Or am I misdiagnosing the situation?

[image: The list of Bluetooth devices]

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311211/no-option-to-remove-bluetooth-device-in-ios-settings-app

Comment: was there an app associated with the device? remove that app and see if that helps.

Comment: @JarrodBrooks yes, I think that was the solution. Would you like to write it as an answer and get sweet karma?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No option to remove Bluetooth device in iOS Settings app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311211/no-option-to-remove-bluetooth-device-in-ios-settings-app)