# One unforgettable bluetooth device!

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

Strangely, I can't find any references to anyone else having this problem. [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311211/no-option-to-remove-bluetooth-device-in-ios-settings-app) is close, but that OP is using a work phone with security profiles that prevent *any* bluetooth settings changes. My problem is that one—only one—bluetooth device is missing the (i) button, which means I can't forget that device. An unforgettable bluetooth pairing! Has anyone seen anything like this before?

[image]

The reason I care, of course, is because I'm having very bad connectivity issues with that one device. The only troubleshooting instructions are to forget and then pair again, but I can't forget!

Comment: you could put the Sonicare devise in your car if possible and park it out of range for Bluetooth. Shouldn't be very far. or if you don't have a car you could ask a friend to store it for you. This way you should be able to determine if thats the cause of your problem. Or maybe just power off the device!  lol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No option to remove Bluetooth device in iOS Settings app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311211/no-option-to-remove-bluetooth-device-in-ios-settings-app)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the Phillips Sonicare product, but there's at least one thing that could potentially explain the lacking (i) indicator: If you have installed a specific Phillips app for use with the product, it could have offered to pair with the device directly from within the app. In that case you can use that specific app to unpair the device again - or you might have to resort to deleting the app if that is possible for you.

Comment: This makes sense to me. However, the app has no pair/forget options. And in fact, the company's own troubleshooting help instructs me to use the (i) in Settings to forget the device, to solve bluetooth communication issues. It sounds like this is basically a bug in the app...