# How to disconnect from mysterious Bluetooth that’s siphoning my sound?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, bluetooth

I noticed that my iPhone 11 Pro wasn’t making any sounds anymore. So I looked into my Bluetooth setting and saw that it was connected to a strange illegible device. It had no (i) icon next to it, so there was no way to forget the device or disconnect from it. The only way for me to get sound back was to completely shut off Bluetooth. If I legitimately wanted to auto connect to those other legible devices, then how should I ban this mystery device?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I’ve reworked my answer to be more comprehensive. Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you ever determine if the mysterious bluetooth was regardless of location, or if it was only in a particular setting?

Comment: @JoseRodriguez The problem is that the database where iOS is storing these devices is corrupted. You may need to back up your device and restore it to fix this if my answer doesn’t shake things free..

Answer (score 2):

The obvious cause is an app you installed placed the connection. Garmin’s companion app for a dashboard camera is [reported to do this.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/354277/5472)

Once you’ve deleted these apps or eliminated the chance it’s an app, the next possibility is a corruption of the database where connections are stored.

Before doing that you might want to sign out of iCloud and restart the device since iCloud sync does also bring a pairing in from another device.

In some cases a three step process let’s me delete “phantom” destinations reliably when the tap to remove doesn’t work.

1. Play video with sound or music and select one of the the headset / speaker options
2. Then Restart the phone
3. Finally, put the phone in Airplane mode and turn off bluetooth and WiFi entirely, shut down the device and then restart and repeat the remove process below

---

Proper functioning device let you remove the pairing as you ask. Hopefully you can restore things without a backup / erase / restore.

Once that’s set, you of course would do the normal action of:

1. Tap the letter i in blue with the circle
2. forget this device.

If there is still no I with a blue circle - you may have a managed device or need to remove the management profile (settings app) or erase the device or reset settings, but your screen shot shows you should be able to just unpair the listed devices. If tapping the i icon doesn't work, your device is malfunctioning and you need to restart it, reset it, erase it or seek service from Apple / other troubleshooting resources.

- [No option to remove Bluetooth device in iOS Settings app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311211/no-option-to-remove-bluetooth-device-in-ios-settings-app)

Answer (score 1):

Another answer that bmike linked seems to have some great ideas: [No option to remove Bluetooth device in iOS Settings app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311211/no-option-to-remove-bluetooth-device-in-ios-settings-app)

Here were the main suggestions:
1) Check for any profiles that might be installed on your phone -- go to Settings--> General--> Profiles. Remove any you don't know and if you can't remove one it may be related to a managed product like a workplace device.

2) Check for applications that may use sound -- someone mentioned Bose has the ability to add a device to there. Then you would delete the application and it would remove the device from the list. Think about any audio programs you might have installed, for example if there's one for a smart speaker or something for a car.

3) Consider erasing and restoring your iPhone or at least choosing General--> Reset Network Settings. Always the last option you want to do.. but if you're really stuck and can't find a solution it may be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Mines my Tesla appvery similar name starts with S2…..random letters & numbers, only shows when app is open in background. My phone seems to pickup within 30 yards of the car indoors or outside doesn’t seem to affect its range. I reckon quit some open apps and that might link with a device.

Setting >general >nobackground app refresh might have something open that’s not showing in app switching.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).